# cuando agrego productos a mi carrito de compras a la hora de darle al carrito no aparecen mis productos y aparece error

Tags: php

Me aparece este error:

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: PDOStatement::execute(): Argument #1 ($params) must be of type ?array, int given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ejercicios\Tienda\chekout.php:17 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ejercicios\Tienda\chekout.php(17): PDOStatement->execute(1) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ejercicios\Tienda\chekout.php on line 17

Este es mi codigo:

```
<?php

require 'config/config.php';
require 'config/database.php';

$db = new Database();
$con = $db -> conectar();

$productos = isset($_SESSION['carrito']['productos']) ? $_SESSION['carrito']['productos'] : null;

$lista_carrito = array();

if($productos != null){

foreach($productos as $clave => $cantidad){
  $sql = $con ->prepare("SELECT id, nombre, precio, descuento, $cantidad as cantidad FROM productos WHERE id = ? AND activo =1");
  $sql -> execute($clave);
  $lista_carrito[] = $sql ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}

}



//session_destroy();

?>




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link  href="css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Tienda</title>
</head>
<body>
    

<header>
  <div class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark shadow-sm">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand  ">
        <img src="images/icono.png" alt="" width="50px">
        <strong>Dragons Company</strong>
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarHeader" aria-controls="navbarHeader" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    <div class ="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarHeader">

        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">

                <a href="#" class="nav-link active">Catalogo</a>

            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">

            <a href="#" class="nav-link active">Contactanos</a>

            
        </li>

        </ul>
        <a href="carrito.php" class="btn btn-primary">
          
          Carrito<span id="num_cart" class="badge bg-secondary"> <?php echo $num_cart; ?></span>
        
        </a>
    </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<main>
<div class="container">

<div class="table-responsive">

  <table class ="table">

  <thead>

  <tr>
    <th>Producto</th>
    <th>Precio</th>
    <th>Cantidad</th>
    <th>SubTotal</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

  </thead>

<tbody>
  <?php if($lista_carrito == null){
    echo '<tr><td colspan= "5" class = "text-center"><b>Lista Vacia</b></td></tr>';
    }else{
      $total = 0;
      foreach($lista_carrito as $producto){
      $_id = $producto['id'];
      $nombre = $producto['nombre'];
      $precio = $producto['precio'];
      $descuento = $producto['descuento'];
      $precio_desc = $precio - (($precio * $desc)/100 );
      $subtotal = $cantidad * $descuento;
      $total += $subtotal;

      ?>
    
    
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $nombre  ?></td>
    <td><?php echo MONEDA.number_format( $precio_desc,2,'.',',')  ?></td>
    <td><input type="number" min="1" max="10" step="1" value= "<?php echo $cantidad; ?>" size="5" id="cantidad_<?php echo $_id; ?>" onchange="" ></td>
    <td>

        <div id="subtotal_<?php echo $_id; ?>" name="subtotal[]"><?php echo MONEDA.number_format( $subtotal,2,'.',',')  ?></div>

    </td>
    <td><a href="#" id="eliminar" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-bs-id="<?php echo $_id; ?>" data-bs-toogle="modal" data-bs-target="eliminaModal">Eliminar</a></td>
  </tr>

<?php } ?>  
</tbody>
<?php } ?>

  </table>

</div>

</div>
</main>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" 
integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>

  function addproducto(id,token) {
    
    let url = 'clases/carrito.php'

    let formData = new FormData()
    
    formData.append('id', id)
    formData.append('token', token)

    fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
      mode: 'cors'
    }).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
      if(data.ok){
        let elemento = document.getElementById("num_cart")
        elemento.innerHTML = data.numero
      }
    })

  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Cuando el carrito esta vacio el codigo funciona, pero cuando añado cosas al carrito el codigo no funciona y me aparece ese error por favor ayuda

Comment: ¿Podrías hacer un `var_dump($productos);` y mostrarnos el resultado? Luego, en el `execute` estarías pasando el índice del array `$productos` que estás leyendo en ese contexto. ¿Es eso lo que quieres? Si es eso, de todos modos, debes pasar el valor como array: `$sql -> execute([$clave]);` porque `execute` espera siempre un array con los valores, sea uno, sean varios, siempre debes pasarlos como array.

Answer (score 0):

[En el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.execute.php) está claro el tipo de parámetro que debes pasar a `execute()`:

```
public PDOStatement::execute(array $input_parameters = ?): bool
```

Se lee claramente **`array`**.

Y, si observas el código del **Ejemplo 3:** verás esto:

```
$gsent->execute(array($calorías, $color));
```

Significa que debes pasar un array a `execute` con los valores. Eso es lo que te dice el mensaje de error:

*`Argument #1 ($params) must be of type ?array, int given ...`*

Espera un array, pero le estás pasando un entero. Quizá la confusión se deba a que es un sólo valor. Pues no importa, sea un valor, sean varios, **siempre** debes pasarlos como array a `execute()`.

Así debería funcionar, salvo otros errores:

```
$sql -> execute(array($clave));
```

Dicho eso, cuando tienes que preparar una consulta en un bucle, es signo de un código mal organizado. Es cierto que hay una columna dinámica que no es otra cosa que el valor de `$cantidad`, pero eso lo puedes mandar en tu resultado final, evitando así preparar la consulta cada vez. Es decir, en vez de meter `$cantidad` en el `SELECT`, la puedes meter en `$lista_carrito[]` ...

Si quieres optimizar, sería algo así:

```
$lista_carrito=array();
$sql = $con ->prepare("SELECT id, nombre, precio, descuento FROM productos WHERE id = ? AND activo =1");
$i=0;
foreach($productos as $clave => $cantidad){
    $sql -> execute(array($clave));
    $lista_carrito[$i]['cantidad'] = $cantidad;
    $lista_carrito[$i] = $sql ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $i++;
}
```